# How to find out whether getLogger created a new object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

How do I find out whether [`getLogger()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.getLogger) returned a new or an existing logger object?

The motivation is that I don't want to `addHandler` repeatedly to the same logger.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129716/how-to-check-if-a-logger-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a particularly clean way to do this... However, if you must, the [source-code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1025) is a pretty good place to start looking in order to figure this out.  Note that [`logging.getLogger`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1567) is mostly a wrapper around `logging.Logger.manager.getLogger`.

The `Manager` keeps a mapping of names -> `Logger` (or `Placeholder`).  If it has `Logger` in the slot designated by a given `name`, it will return it.  Otherwise, it'll return a new `Logger`.

```
import logging
def has_logger(name):
    manager = logging.Logger.manager
    if name in manager.loggerDict:
        return isinstance(manager.loggerDict[name], logging.Logger)
    else:
        return False
```

Note that this only handles the case where you have *named* loggers.  If you do `logging.getLogger()` (without passing a name), then it simply will return the root logger which is created at import time (and therefore, it is never new).

Another approach could be to get a logger and check that it's `handlers` list is smaller than you'd expect (i.e. if it isn't an empty list, then handlers have been added).

```
def has_handlers(logger):
    """Return True if logger has handlers, False otherwise."""
    return bool(logger.handlers)
```

Answer (score 0):

getLogger will return a singleton instance over the named logger, to check that

```
import logging

id_ = id(logging.getLogger())

for i in range(10):
    assert id_ == id(logging.getLogger())
```

For logging purpose i used to used à logger module looking like:

mylogger.py

```
import logging
import logging.config

from pathlib import Path


logging.config.fileConfig(str(Path(__file__).parent / "logging.conf"),
                          disable_existing_loggers=False)

def get(name="MYLOG", **kw):

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.propagate = True
    if kw.get('level'):
        logger.setLevel(kw.get('level'))
    else:
        logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    return logger
```

All handlers are defined in the [logging.conf](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/#example-configuration-via-an-ini-file)