# How to check if a logger exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-handling, python-logging

I've had to extend the existing logging library to add some features. One of these is a feature which lets a handler listen to any existing log without knowing if it exists beforehand. The following allows the handler to listen, but does not check if the log exists:

```
def listen_to_log(target, handler):
    logging.getLogger(target).addHandler(handler)
```

The issue is that I don't want any handler to listen to a log which isn't being logged to, and want to raise a `ValueError` if the log doesn't already exist. Ideally I'd do something like the following:

```
def listen_to_log(target, handler):
    if not logging.logExists(target):
        raise ValueError('Log not found')
    logging.getLogger(target).addHandler(handler)
```

So far I have been unable to find a function like `logging.logExists`, is there such a function, or a convenient workaround?

Comment: There is a dict you could check, see here: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/621740/ but it is undocumented, I think.

Comment: That's perfect, I'd be happy to accept if you provide it as answer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

***Workaround that works for me and possibly you:***

When you create a logger for your own code, you will almost certainly create a logger with handlers (file handler and/or console handler).
When you have not yet created a logger and you get the 'root' logger by

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

then this logger will have no handlers yet.
Therefore, I always check whether the logger above results in a logger that has handlers by

```
logging.getLogger().hasHandlers()
```

So I create a logger only if the root logger does not have handlers:

```
logger = <create_my_logger> if not logging.getLogger().hasHandlers() else logging.getLogger()
```

The "create_my_logger" snippet represents my code/function that returns a logger (with handlers).

Comment: this is also useful in concurrent logging where loggers may survive process reuse.

Comment: "When you create a logger for your own code, you will almost certainly create a logger with handlers". Yes, in that case your method works. For instance, logging.basicConfig does it for you. On the other hand, if you previously created a logger without a specified name and without any handlers, you cannot distinguish it from a new, similarly created logger. The reason is that the root logger is not stored in the logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict dictionary, as @VPfB points it out in his answer.

Comment: If you are using < Python 3.2, you can use `len(logger.handlers)` instead of `logger.hasHandlers()`

Answer (score 18):

WARNING. This is not documented. It may change without notice.

The logging module internally uses a single `Manager` object to hold the hierarchy of loggers in a dict accessible as:

```
import logging
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict
```

All loggers **except the root logger** are stored in that dict under their names.

There are few examples on the net:
http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/621740/
and
https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/use-of-the-logging-module-in-python.html (uses Python 2 print)